# Dynamically adding options to a jQuery Mobile Optgroup

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue adding options dynamically.  Currently I have an optgroup with some hardcoded values in my html:

```
<select id="opt1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="left">
                <optgroup label="optgroup options" id = "opt">
                    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

I would like to add options to this dynamically from my database.  Currently I am trying to do it like this:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {

transaction.executeSql('SELECT input FROM ListInput WHERE input != ""', [],
                       function(transaction, result) {
                       if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                       for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                       var row = result.rows.item(i);
                       $('#opt').append('<option>'+ row['input'] + '</option>');

                       }

                       }

                       $("#opt").selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh');
                       },errorHandler);
},errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

But, this isn't adding the options correctly.  The option just appears on the select menu and when I click the menu to see the options, it doesn't have it's own checkbox and doesn't display at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just calling selectmenu('refresh') on the wrong DOM element. You should call it on the select not the option group. So change this line:

```
$("#opt").selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh');
```

to

```
$("#opt1").selectmenu('refresh');
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lcbmh/)**

Comment: Thanks so much, this almost works perfectly.  Just one thing, when I dynamically add the first option, it appears as the title of the optgroup rather than an option inside it.  In your demo "new option0" does the same.  Is there any way to change this?

Comment: @Mohd, It looks like jQM is adding data-placeholder="true" to the first added item that does not have a value attribute. So you can either give your options value attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lcbmh/2/ or just provide a static placeholder: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lcbmh/1/